# Accordeon expand collapse, one more option

Tags: html, css, menu

I'm trying to make a responsive menu for the cellphone-size.
What I want is a collapseable navigation-menu, for example:

- (not expanding) BUTTON A
- (not expanding) BUTTON B
- (expandable) BUTTON C
- BUTTON C option A

So when you see the menu first, you only see button A,B and C.
When you click on Button C, below it appears (by clicking on it) the option A.

What I have so far is a button with a three-lines nav icon.
When you click on it, you see button a,b,c .
But when you click on Button c, the whole list collapse back, and when re-opening, you see the full list. This is not what I had in mind...

My coding:
**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".text").hide();
        $(".accordeon div:first-child").addClass("expand_first");
        $(".expand").click(function() {
                $(".text").slideUp(500);
                if ($(this).next(".text").is(":visible")) {
                        $(this).next(".text").slideUp(500);
                } else {
                        $(this).next(".text").slideToggle(500);
                }
        });
});
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
$('ul li a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('ul.sub-menu').toggle();
    return false;
});
</script>

<div id="nav-small">
        <div class="accordeon">
                <div class="expand"><img src="http://localhost:8080/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/navicon.png" alt="Navigation" width="50%" height="auto" />
                      Navigation
                </div>
                <div class="text">      
                <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
                <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Lifestyle</a>▼
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Cleaning & Organizing</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Health & Beauty</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                </ul>

</div></div></div>
```

My **CSS**:

```
#nav-small{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
#nav-small img{
    width:50%;
    max-width:30px;
    max-height:30px;
}
#nav-small ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-family:verdana;
}
#nav-small ul li{
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 2% 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
#nav-small ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
#nav-small ul li.sub-menu{
    border-bottom:none;
    padding-bottom:0;
}
.accordeon{
    text-align:center;
    background-color: rgba(104,144,192,1.00) ;
    width:100%;
}
.accordeon .expand {
    display:inline-block;
    width:30%;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
    font-family: Verdana;
    background-color: rgba(104,144,192,1.00) ;
    cursor:pointer;
    padding:1% 0;
    border-left:1px solid #ccc;
    border-right:1px solid #ccc;
}
.accordeon .text{
        display:none;
    float:left;
        width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin:auto;
        border-top:0px;
        border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
        background-color: rgba(211,196,213,1.00);
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: Demo here https://jsfiddle.net/qo1dg5p8/

Comment: Ty :) So I want the 3 options (cleaning, health and travel) only to appear when I click on the ▼-sign.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qo1dg5p8/1/ like this ?

Comment: YES ! EXACTLY LIKE THIS ! :D THANK YOU SO MUCH :P

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

Wrap your icon in a span to add a selector and add a click event listener to it.
Also I added a class that uses `display: none` for your nested ul.

---

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oephv49a/)

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".text").hide();
  $(".accordeon div:first-child").addClass("expand_first");
  $(".expand").click(function() {
    $(".text").slideUp(500);
    if ($(this).next(".text").is(":visible")) {
      $(this).next(".text").slideUp(500);
    } else {
      $(this).next(".text").slideToggle(500);
    }
  });
  $("#trigger").on("click", function() {
    $(".sub-menu > ul").slideToggle(500, function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("is-not-visible");
    });
  });

});
$(window).load(function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider();
});
$('ul li a').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('ul.sub-menu').toggle();
  return false;
});
```

```css
#nav-small {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#nav-small img {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 30px;
  max-height: 30px;
}

#nav-small ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: verdana;
}

#nav-small ul li {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 2% 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#nav-small ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordeon {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(104, 144, 192, 1.00);
  width: 100%;
}

.accordeon .expand {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: Verdana;
  background-color: rgba(104, 144, 192, 1.00);
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 1% 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.accordeon .text {
  display: none;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  border-top: 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: rgba(211, 196, 213, 1.00);
  text-align: left;
}

.is-not-visible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav-small">
  <div class="accordeon">
    <div class="expand"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="Navigation" width="50%" height="auto" /> Navigation
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
        <li class="sub-menu"><a href="#">Lifestyle</a> <span id="trigger">▼</span>
          <ul class="is-not-visible">
            <li><a href="#">Cleaning & Organizing</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Health & Beauty</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You too, tyvm ! :D